# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'schools.submit_application_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel-5.4

I get this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'schools.submit_application_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `schools` where `schools`.`submit_application_id` = 1 and
>   `schools`.`submit_application_id` is not null) (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\tvto\resources\views\Admin\inspectors-list\all.blade.php)

InspectionListController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $inspectors_lists = SubmitApplication::latest()->where('approved', 1)->get();
    return view('Admin.inspectors-list.all', compact('inspectors_lists'));
}
```

all.blade.php

```
<td>{{ $inspectors_list->school_list->user->first_name }}</td>
```

SubmitApplication.php

```
public function school_lists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

SchoolsList.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function submit_application()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubmitApplication::class);
}
```

SubmitApplication.php

```
public function school_lists()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function schools()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SchoolsList::class);
}
```

For SubmitApplication table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('submit_applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('school_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->integer('approved')->nullable(true);
        $table->string('application')->nullable(true);
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions');
        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools');
    });
}
```

For SchoolList table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('schools', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('province_name');
        $table->string('center_name');
        $table->string('national_number_founder');
        $table->string('school_name');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Comment: Echo your select statement and paste here.Let a look what query create your function

Comment: Echo my select statement

Comment: Answer my questuin.

Comment: I am telling you friend just echo your query and check whether it is correct or your column  submit_application_id is valid in your table.

Comment: What does it mean?